# How to generate random sample with controlled repetition?

Tags: sampling, random-variable

Let's say I want to generate 100 numbers.

If I don't allow for any duplications it would go from 1 to 100. But I want to allow for 20% of duplications i.e. so to 20% of the sample would be non-unique -- how can I do that?

Comment: Owing to the unusual request and the subtleties of randomization, could you please say more about the purpose of this procedure (and, especially, what the repetition needs to accomplish)?

Comment: I agree with whuber. This is a weird way of thinking about randomization, and you may end up with a procedure that does not achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not responded to requests (from 8 years ago).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a load of ways to interpret what you asked for.

In R this will generate what you asked for allowing every number to repeat any number of times with 20% of the values being repetitions.

```
myRandomNumbers <- sample(c(1:80, sample(1:80, 20, replace = TRUE)))
```

Or, perhaps you just wanted to have one repetition of 20% of the unique values...

```
myRandomNumbers <- sample(c(1:80, sample(1:80, 20)))
```

You really need to specify your request better.